# DB2 to Oracle Migration

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-11g, db2

I am migrating a very large and complex database from DB2 to Oracle 11g.  Can someone suggest any tools / processes to do this very quickly.  My database is about 500 GB and it cannot have downtime much more than about 4-6 hours maybe a little more but not much.

Source: Linux SuSE 11 64 Bits - DB2 9.7
Target: Linux Redhat 64 Bits - Oracle 11G

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Q replication, as it is explained here:
http://www.thefillmoregroup.com/blog/?cat=49

http://smarterquestions.org/2012/02/video-the-fillmore-group-on-jp-morgans-successful-migration-from-oracle-to-ibm/